# Chef custom resource action properties not working

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm having an issue with a custom resource I created in a new cookbook i'm working on. When I do a kitchen converge on the following setup I get the following error:

```
error: NoMethodError: undefined method `repository_url' for PoiseApplicationGit::Resource
```

Info about my development machine:

- Chef Development Kit Version: 2.1.11
- chef-client version: 13.2.20
- delivery version: master (73ebb72a6c42b3d2ff5370c476be800fee7e5427)
- berks version: 6.3.0
- kitchen version: 1.17.0
- inspec version: 1.33.1

Here's my custom resource under resources/deploy.rb:

```
resource_name :opsworks_deploy

property :app_path, String, name_property: true
property :app_name, String, required: true
property :repository_url, String, required: true
property :repository_key, String, required: true
property :short_name, String, required: true
property :app_type, String, required: true
property :app, Object, required: true
property :permission, String, required: true

action :deploy do    
  apt_update 'update'

  # Install NGinx
  package 'nginx' do
    not_if { ::File.exist?("/etc/init.d/nginx") }
  end

  # Setup the app directory
  directory my_app_path do
    owner 'www-data'
    group 'www-data'
    mode '0755'
    recursive true
  end

  slack_notify "notify_deployment_end" do
    message "App #{app_name} deployed successfully"
    action :nothing
  end

  slack_notify "notify_nginx_reload" do
    message "Nginx has reloaded"
    action :nothing
  end

  slack_notify "notify_nginx_config" do
    message "Nginx site config has been updated for #{app_name}"
    action :nothing
  end

  slack_notify "notify_git_deploy" do
    message "App #{app_name} has been checkout out from git"
    action :nothing
  end

  slack_notify "notify_file_permissions" do
    message "App #{app_name} has been given proper file permissions"
    action :nothing
  end

  # Deploy git repo from opsworks app
  application app_path do
    owner 'www-data'
    group 'www-data'

    git do
      user 'root'
      group 'root'
      repository my_repo_url
      deploy_key my_repo_key
      notifies :notify, "slack_notify[notify_git_deploy]", :immediately
    end

    execute "chown-data-www" do
      command "chown -R www-data:www-data #{my_app_path}"
      user "root"
      action :run
      notifies :notify, "slack_notify[notify_file_permissions]", :immediately
    end

    # Setup the nginx config file for the site
    template "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{my_short_name}" do
      source "#{my_app_type}.erb"
      owner "root"
      group "root"
      mode 0644
      variables( :app => my_app )
      notifies :notify, "slack_notify[notify_nginx_config]", :immediately
    end

    # Reload nginx
    service "nginx" do
      supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true, :stop => true, :start => true
      action :reload
      notifies :notify, "slack_notify[notify_nginx_reload]", :immediately
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my recipe under recipes/default.rb (all variables are set properly and to the proper types, i'm using test data bags and they are correctly passing):

```
command = search(:aws_opsworks_command).first
deploy_app = command[:args][:app_ids].first
app = search(:aws_opsworks_app, "app_id:#{deploy_app}").first
app_path = "/var/www/" + app[:shortname]

opsworks_deploy app_path do
  app_name app[:name]
  app_type app[:environment][:APP_TYPE]
  repository_url app[:app_source][:url]
  repository_key app[:app_source][:ssh_key]
  short_name app[:shortname]
  app app
  permission '0755'
end
```

The only way I can get it working is if I add this at the top of the action declaration and update the properties within to match:

```
action :deploy do
    my_repo_url = repository_url.dup
    my_repo_key = repository_key.dup
    my_app_path = app_path.dup
    my_app_type = app_type.dup
    my_short_name = short_name.dup
    my_app = app.dup
    ...
```

Any reason why this is the case? Should I have to redeclare them like that in the action?

Answer (score 0):

Use `new_resource.repository_url` and similar. The magic aliasing doesn't work correctly in a lot of circumstances and we've formally deprecated it as of 13.1 (though it's been not recommended for a while).

Comment: Still doesn't work. It only works if I add this at the top of the action:

`this_resource = new_resource`

and then use `this_resource.respository_url`

why is that?

Comment: It's possible my app sub resource code isn't working right in this case. I don't think I've tested this kind of usage.

Comment: Related: why are you forcing the git clone to run as root and then chowning afterwards?

Comment: I've been having problems with can't unlink files, even though the permissions are correct and the u/g are set correctly. For the meantime I've patched it like that until I can address it fully.

Comment: If you can make a minimal repro case, please drop me an issue on Github.